# Looking for c# packet capture library

Tags: c#, networking, packet

i'm writing C# code in visual studio2015 and im looking for packet capture library

my goal is to reject some non-allowed packets and ddos attack

Comment: Asking for recommendations for tools/products is considered off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know of one library that can do it for windows: [WinDivert](https://www.reqrypt.org/windivert.html)
It also has a .net wrapper: [Divert.Net](https://github.com/TechnikEmpire/Divert.Net). For the Divert.Net you need the 1.2.0-rc MSVC files from what I remember.